# Can't activate Windows 10 after clean install ("product key is blocked")

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, windows-activation

I had Windows 10 in my laptop. I performed a clean install due to Inaccessible_Boot_Device error that prevented me from starting it at all. After the clean install Windows starts normally but it is not activated. I upgraded from windows 8.1 Home before. According to Microsoft, Windows shall be activated even after a clean install as long as it was first installed using the free upgrade. How can i resolve this issue? Is there a way to extract it from BIOS?

I have HP Envy dv6.

Update: I reset the device. Same problem. Then i restarted it and there is a new thing. In the activation section in "Update & Security" it says: connect to the internet to activate Windows. And there is error details in the same section that says: The activation server determined the specified product key is blocked. !!!!! What is that?

Comment: It sounds like the installation of Windows 10 you did have installed never activated, if that is the case, not much you can about your current situation except to install Windows 8.1 and then upgrade to Windows 10.  There is nothing to extract from your BIOS because, the only thing contained within it, is your Windows 8.1 license.  A Windows 8.1 license **cannot** be used to install Windows 10 for obvious reasons ( *the obvious reason being of course it isn't a Windows 10 license* )

Comment: Are there any activation errors? You can check if Windows is activated by going to `Settings`. If it is not activated, there will be a message at the bottom that says *Windows isn't activated. Activate Windows now.* From there you can click the link, which will bring you to `Activate Windows`. You can then choose to `Activate Windows Online` or `Enter a new product key`. If you use the new product key method, you could try using the key that was for your Windows 8.1. Let us know the information that `Activate Windows` gives you.

Comment: please see the question update.

Comment: @onlyforthis  - Use the phone activation method.  We cannot tell you the reason for your activation is being blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted MS Customer support. He asked for remote access to the device.He first refused to help activating it. He Told me that i didn't upgrade from Windows 8.1. Finally he ran slui4.exe and activated it by phone. He could've told me To do that :(. Long story short, Check phone activation method if you have the same problem or contact MS Technical support.

Answer (score -2):

Follow the guide specifically at -http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/help-upgrade-windows-10

Then the Activation - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950929

You may do well to get on the phone (there is a phone link) on the Activation Page - if the key is locked, nobody here is going to be able to help you and you need to talk with Microsoft to get it sorted out.

Comment: It would be nice if the relevant information was in the answer itself, an answer should be self-contained, only using a link as a citation and/or external resource.

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound - but the user is going to have to go to Microsoft to sort this out.  Neither you nor me are going to be able to unlock this person's registration key!!  It does not seem that hard to figure out!!!

Comment: What does that have to do with including the relevant information for your resource?

Comment: Activation..  If he is having a Activation Problem (my Activation is locked) then Microsoft will have to unlock and validate his key.

Comment: I simply provided feedback when I downvoted the answer for being unhelpful due to the fact all it contains is a single statement and two urls, without the relevant information even being provided, so when those urls are moved ( and Microsoft has a nasty habit of doing that without a redirection ) the urls will be dead.

Comment: @Ramhound - I am leaving the answer as it is.  I don't mind that you graded me down.  I maintain my answer and I don't care if you change it or ??  I don't do this for the "atta boys" anyway.  If i need to get service with my car, I am going to mechanic or the dealer - People around here should be technically savvy enough to perform a search to figure out how to solve their own issues.

Comment: I keep on leaving comments to your answers, and I keep reading answers that don't really seem to fully answer the propose questions, and I still don't understand how my feedback is confusing. There is a ton of information between those two links, and the author of the question, is unlikely to know what is important and relevant to his problem.  I **could** change the answer, but I won't because I can change it without a review, so I would just submit my own answer.  You have to write answers so anyone can understand them, because people come here, for technical help because they are not savvy.